# How to re-use the same controller by different form inputs

Tags: cakephp

Here is the portion of my view:

```
echo $this->Form->create("Provider", array('action' => 'view_admit_lookup', ''));
echo $this->Form->input("last_name", array('label' => 'Doctor Last Name'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Search');
echo "<br><br>";

$alphabet = array(
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
    "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X",
    "Y", "Z");
foreach($alphabet as $letter):
    // create the row of buttons that are responsible for the search.
    echo $this->Form->button($letter, array('action' => 'view_admit_lookup'));
endforeach;
```

Now, I'd like to be able to modify and re-use view_admit_lookup.

Here is that method in my controller:

```
function view_admit_lookup($letter) {
    echo "<pre>The letter is: ".$letter."</pre>";

    // here we begin searching for whatever we need.
    if(!empty($this->data['Provider']['last_name'])) {
        $this->set('provider',
            $this->Provider->find('all',
                                      array('conditions' =>
                                          array('Provider.last_name LIKE' =>
                                            $this->data['Provider']['last_name'].'%'),
                                            'order' =>
                                          array('Provider.last_name ASC',
                                                'Provider.first_name ASC'),
                                           )
                                  )
                  );
    }

    // set the title and the default layout.
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Admit Lookup');
    $this->layout = 'default';
}
```

How can I 'get' the letter associated with the input (button or text field), and perform a particular operation based on that value?

Comment: On a side tangent, instead of `$alphabet = array( 'A', 'B', 'C', ... 'Z' );`, you can simplify with `$alphabet = range( 'A', 'Z' );`  http://php.net/range

Answer (score 1):

Your current method of adding an 'action' to `$this->Form->button()` is incorrect.  According to the Cake docs, ["$options is used primarily to specify HTML tag attributes"](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1413/Form-Element-Specific-Methods).  A button input does not have an action attribute. The action attribute belongs to the form element.

*In reponse to your comment:*
There is no purpose to `$this->Form->button($letter, array('action' => 'view_admit_lookup'));`  This line of Cake should produce the following HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="A" action="view_admit_lookup">
```

This line of HTML does not make sense and will not actually do anything.  You should read up on HTML forms as it does not appear you fully understand how they work.  Suggested reading:

- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
- http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms12.htm

Your problem is that all the buttons are part of the same form with no clear way to send the letter corresponding to the clicked button.  The 2 ways that I think would work easiest for you are...

1. **HTML**
   Create a separate `<form>` element for each button. Each form can pass the letter in 1 of 2 ways:

   1. Adding the corresponding letter to the form's action.
   2. Adding the corresponding letter to a hidden `<input>` element in each form.

   Then you change your button from a standard `<input>` button to a `<submit>` button and it will submit a separate form for each letter button.

   Something like this:

   ```
   <form action="view_admit_lookup/a" method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="A">
   </form>
   <form action="view_admit_lookup/b" method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="B">
   </form>
   <form action="view_admit_lookup/c" method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="C">
   </form>
   ...
   ```
2. **JavaScript**
   Have 1 `<form>` element with all of the letter buttons and capture each button's `click` action with a JavaScript function.  Use this function to populate a hidden `<input>` with the click data and submit the form.

   Something like this:

   ```
   <form action="view_admit_lookup" method="get">
     <input type="hidden" name="VAL" id="VAL">
     <input type="submit" value="A" onclick="return setVAL('a');">
     <input type="submit" value="A" onclick="return setVAL('a');">
     ...
   </form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function setVAL(letter){
     document.getElementById('VAL').value = letter;
     return true;
   }
   </script>
   ```

Depending on the method you choose, you can access the letter in your controller function using either `$this->params` or `$this->data`.

Comment: Wait, so CakePHP generates a button that can't be used for anything?

Comment: @gp443 It's not Cake's fault -- a "bog standard" HTML `<input type="button">` does nothing at all unless you hook it into a form submit or other JavaScript-enabled actions.  This is an HTML thing.

Comment: So what purpose would this serve:

echo $this->Form->button($letter, array('action' => 'view_admit_lookup'));

Comment: @gp443 Formulated as it is, no purpose at all.  The answer has been revised with more detail.